# AWS File misplacement

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a project deployed on EC2 instance and is up.
But sometime when I login through FTP and transfer the updated build to the EC2, some of my project file gets missing.
After a while those set of files is seen listed at the same place.

Couldn't relate why these unexpected behavior is happening. Let me know if anyone has faced similar kind of situation.

Or anyone can give me a way to know what all logins are being done through FTP and SSH on my EC2.

Answer (score 1):

Files don't just randomly go missing on an EC2 instance. I suspect there is something going on and you'll need to diagnose it. There is not enough information here to help you but I can try point you in the right direction.

A few things that come to mind are:

What are you running to execute the ftp command? If it's appearing after some time, are you sure it's just not in progress when you first check then it appears when it's done? are you sure nothing is being cached?

Are you sure your FTP client is connected to the right instance?

Are you sure there are no cron tasks or external entities connecting to the instance and cleaning out a certain directory? You said something about the build, is this a build agent you're performing this on?

I highly doubt it's this one but: What type of volume are you working on? EBS? Instance Store? Instance Store is ephemeral so stopping/starting the instance can result in data being lost.

Have you tried using `scp` ?

If you're still stumped, please provide more info on your ec2 config and how you're transferring the file.